# Why are the equals sign "=" and plus sign "+" not special characters in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, passwords, amazon-cognito, password-protection, policy

While deploying our new authentication application this morning we encountered issues with users having unsecured passwords. In our development logic, consider the equals sign "=" and the plus sign "+" special characters.

**Why would this statement be valid and logical ?**

> "The equals sign "=" and the plus sign "+" are not considered special
>   characters."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-policies.html

We are trying to understand the logic regarding this decision.

Any insight ?

Comment: Trying to get anwsers from AWS Community too :
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=930895&#930895